# Fetch and assign colorpicker hexa values as a background in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html, color-picker

I am running angularJS project and i have taken HTML color picker, i want to assign the selected color from colorpicker to my div. Values should be hexa decimal.My code is as follows.

```
   <input type="color" id="html5colorpicker" style="width:85%;">

   <div>Testing for bachground color </div>
```

Or is there any other control which i can you use for the above purpose(Angularjs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `background-color` property and assign hexadecimal value to that

```html
<div style="background-color: #a9a1a1;">Testing for bachground color </div>
```

**EDITED**

you need to use `ng-style` attribute to bind the style after the color selected from the color picker.

first use ng-model to get the selected color value

```
<input type="color" id="html5colorpicker" ng-model="mycolor" />
<div ng-style="divStyle">Testing for bachground color </div>
```

In the controller create a watch for `ng0model` variable and add the style to `divStyle`

```
 $scope.divStyle = {
    'background-color': 'white'
 }
 $scope.$watch('mycolor', function(val) {
    $scope.divStyle = {
        'background-color': val
    }
 });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7f5ya562/103/)

Comment: i want to use value from colorpicker which will be shown after i click on the input box '<input type="color" id="html5colorpicker" style="width:85%;">'

Comment: ahh so can u get the selected value to scope variable

Comment: I am not getting how should i take values from colorpicker because as of now i just have html control input box..

Comment: yeah i want that way only!!! thanks a lot. just one small query what does the $scope.watch do? and one more thing i forgot to mention i am using single page application(ngRoute) so will it work for it as well my click event code is in ts file.

Comment: watch is a scope function. Every time 'mycolor' change it will trigger. basically one of the angular popular concept call two way binding is possible because of the watch. parameter `val` is the new value of that variable. does't matter if are using ngRoute or ui-router it will work